# Outsource source code in docker-compose to use minimal disk space

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins, docker-compose

I am using docker successfully in dev environment and want to use it now at staging and prod too.

I am developing a web application with symfony where the code is mounted local to the docker container. For staging and prod i want to "bake" the source code to the image, cause theres no need to change it anymore at this time.

At the moment my services "php" and "nginx" needs access to the src files. For staging/prod i would create a extra volume called "src" and mount it to both services. In one of the services (nginx/php) i would add a COPY command to copy the src code on build to the mounted "src" volume.

The problem now is the following:

Whenever a new version of my code exist, the whole image have to build new ... the smallest image (nginx) has a size of 200MB. So every time i want to update only my code (size just 10MB) the whole container (200MB) has to build new ...

In addition i want to check in all builds into a repository.

That is quite expensive with time ...

My thought is the following:
Is it possible to only build the data volume "src" new on each code update (triggered trough a jenkins build job) and check them in?

I think, there is no need to build rarely changed environments like php/nginx/mysql new on every build ...

Or is there another approach?

Initially having 1,5GB for all needed services is quite ok, But having for each version another 200 MB in the repository is too heavy.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First the approach you are following is definitely a bad practice. A docker container should be portable and self-contained. Relying on data volumes that are bounded to the host machine will make your container not portable.

By design containers should package all of the dependencies needed to run the application. You should thus add the source to each image if the source code is a dependency that must be provided.

You should investigate other options to make the image size smaller. Depending on the programming language you are using, it is possible to compile/compress the source code and have a smaller binary for instance that can be copied into the image.

One final note is that using very different appraoches to deploy between environment(dev/staging/prod) is usually a bad idea. It is much preferable to have similar deployment strategies to avoid unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your Dockerfile properly ([see docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)) so you are adding the code last, it should be a pretty quick operation to update as all the other unchanged layers will be cached. This is pretty common practice as part of a Docker workflow.

You can use this same image for your local development and mount your working code over the code in the container for active development. As long as that exact same code is used to rebuild your images, you should maintain consistency. You could optimize further by choosing which parts of your code are likely to change and order your build accordingly.

You may also want to look into [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) process where you can further optimize your base image and reduce final image size.